# MySQL JSON_EXTRACT wildcard field name matching

Tags: mysql, json

I have following JSON data in MySQL JSON FIELD

```
{
   "Session0":[
      {
         "r_type":"main",
         "r_flag":"other"
      },
      {
         "r_type":"sub",
         "r_flag":"kl"
      }
   ],
   "Session1":[
      {
         "r_type":"up",
         "r_flag":"p2"
      },
      {
         "r_type":"id",
         "r_flag":"mb"
      }
   ],
   "Session2":[
      {
         "r_type":"main",
         "r_flag":"p2"
      },
      {
         "r_type":"id",
         "r_flag":"mb"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I wish to search ALL sessions where r_type="main". The session number can vary, hence I can not use a OR query. So, I need something like: where

```
JSON_EXTRACT(field,"$.Session**[*].r_type")="main"
```

But this does not seem to work. I need to be able to use wildcard in the property's name and then search an array for a property inside it. How do I do that?

Following work's, but that limits our ability to have unlimited Sessions numbers.

```
SELECT field->"$.Session1[*].r_type" from table
```

Comment: I am not sure you can extract the desired values in one run. Would you need all the data where the `r_type` equals to `main`? For example: `"Session0":[{"r_type":"main","r_flag":"other"},{"r_type":"sub","r_flag":"kl"}` and `"Session2": ...`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its more about searching for data that has say "r_type":"main", irrespective of sessions, and sometimes for a particular Session. The only way we found so far is either remove session part, and make it an array i.e. Sessions:[ [{},{},{}],[],[] ] or perhaps make it a property, Session_no:1.

Comment: Maybe `JSON_SEARCH` can gives new idea, but it would still need some other processing. For example: `SELECT JSON_SEARCH(field, 'all', 'main') FROM your_table;` gives you an array of paths that have `main` as value: `["$.Session0[0].r_type", "$.Session2[0].r_type"]`.

Comment: That is the thing though, in a real world situation you want the db to fetch it with a single query for performance reasons. Can not be doing layers upon layers. There is the option of using REGEXP directly instead, but I believe index on functions feature on mysql is precious here to get the desired performance, so ideally want a direct mysql solution. For now, we have resorted to transforming the data into a format that works. But I am not too happy with that.

Comment: That is true. You could use indexed, generated columns. What about that direction?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned for the moment we transformed the input data itself to save it a certain format which works with json_extract, and for the moment that is the solution, and we will index it. But I see a situation very soon using an alternative. As our work goes ahead, we will look at it again. Hopefully, somebody will also come up with wildcard property name syntax. So far though, that is the solution regex or other custom function with index.